# How to use the Harmony Configurator with AWS FreeRTOS project in MPLAB

Tags: pic, mplab

I'm trying to setup a new project for PIC32WFI32E, I have downloaded the AWS FreeRTOS git repository. My issue is that if I open the project then I cannot make use MPLAB Harmony Configurator to setup UART, pins etc. When i try to open the configurator i just get an error message saying "This project may not have been created with MPLAB Harmony Configurator".

Is there a way that I can use the configurator and use the AWS FreeRTOS project?

Thanks,
Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with repository: "https://github.com/MicrochipTech/amazon-freertos".